# Wordpress installation in my app/webroot/blog folder of CakePHP

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cakephp

I have a wordpress installation in my app/webroot/blog folder of CakePHP, i access normally to my www.example.com/blog/, but when i enter to an article i loose the link, for example i get www.example.com/blog/app/webroot/blog/?p=1

Is there a solution to fix that? i think i should modify my wordpress .htaccess but i don't know what to add.

my wordpress .htaccess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My Cakephp app/.htaccess is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

And my Cakephp app/webroot/.htaccess is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Cheers

Comment: This [blog](http://www.balistupa.com/blog/2010/08/how-to-redirect-appwebrootblog-into-blog-wordpress-cakephp/) may helps you.

Answer (score 2):

The way I did it was to put the wordpress folder inside the root, and call it /blog.

Note that this isn't going into Cake's webroot folder, it's just putting the folder in the actual root, alongside /app, /lib, /plugins etc.

Then I modified the root's .htaccess file to look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /

   # Disable rewriting for the wordpress blog
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/ [NC]
   RewriteRule    (.*) $1    [L]

   # Normal CakePHP rewriting
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This seemed like the best way to completely separate the cake parts of the site from the wordpress parts.

It works well for me.